# MS SQL Report Builder expressions

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm new to Report Builder but an expert in SQL, Crystal and Excel. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make expressions choose between various criteria.

Basically, I have a SQL view that gives me something like this...

```
Type   CurrMonth PrevMonth
------ --------- ---------
Actual    123.45  456.78
Budget    178.91  578.56
```

and all I want to do is set up a guage or chart that shows actual vs budget.

So for the 'Actual' field I'm trying to do an expression like this...

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Type.Value, "Guages") = "Actual",Sum(Fields!CurrMonth.Value, "Guages"),0)
```

...If the type is "Actual" then show 'CurrMonth', else 0

I'm not understanding why I can't get it to work - I just want to show one bar in a chart to be the 'actual' and another bar to be 'budget' - but I can't seem to get it to filter.

The online help isn't providing a solution either so I'd like to know how everyone does this.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: You are an "expert" in SQL, Crystal, and Excel but don't know how to google the syntax of a basic VB `IIF()` statement? `IIF(Expression, True, False)`

Comment: ...I get that, but it doesn't work

Comment: Is your dataset called "Guages"?  I'm assuming it isn't, but if the data is being used in a gauge, the dataset doesn't need to be specified like that.  You could probably shorten this to `=IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Actual"), Sum(Fields!CurrMonth.Value), 0)`.

Comment: Yes, it is, I've got one datasource which brings in two views as datasets, one for a table and the other for the guages - I populated the IFF by double clicking on the fields as I assumed that it would give me the correct syntax to populate the formula - I'll give it a go without the dataset names.

Comment: It works fine with bar charts as you can use grouping to separate the Type.

Comment: assuming your sample data was real, can you edit your question to show a mock up of exactly what you expect to see on your gauge.